# User defined directory for a c++ system function to execute from

Tags: c++, system

```
system("mkdir C:\\Users\\USER\\Desktop\\test");
```

i found this however this does not work because my code looks like this

```
string inputFAT = "input.FAT";
    string outputdirecotry = "adirectory";
    string exepath = "FATool.exe";

    cout << "enter the directory you would like to have the files put out to";
    getline(cin, outputdirecotry);
    string outputdirectorycommand = "cd " + outputdirecotry;


    cout << "enter the path of the file you want to extract";
    getline(cin, inputFAT);

    cout << "enter the path to the FATool executable";
    getline(cin, exepath);

    string  exportcommand = exepath + " -x " + inputFAT;
    system(outputdirectorycommand.c_str && exportcommand.c_str());
```

as you can see i need the user to define the directory that the system function needs to go to and when i try to build it it throws these errors

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   C3867   'std::basic_string,std::allocator>::c_str': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member    FATool++    c:\users\russ\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\fatool++\fatool++\main.cpp  24

and also this

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   C2664   'int system(const char *)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'bool' to 'const char *' FATool++    c:\users\russ\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\fatool++\fatool++\main.cpp  24

so is it even possible to do this or should i just take my loses and define the directory myself and have my friends go into the code and do the same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter passed to `system()` is wrong:

```
system(outputdirectorycommand.c_str && exportcommand.c_str());
```

The syntax `outputdirectorycommand.c_str` is wrong, and the parameter passed to `system()` is `bool` which is obviously wrong.

Assume what you want to do is to execute `cd <x> && FATool.exe -x <xxx>`, then you should `cat` your command and pass it to `system()`:

```
string cmdToExecute = outputdirectorycommand + " && " + exportcommand;
system(cmdToExecute.c_str());
```

Comment: wow okay thanks i never taught about doing that it now seems so obvious

Answer (score 1):

```
system(outputdirectorycommand.c_str && exportcommand.c_str());
```

This tries to take the address of the std::string::c_str function, convert it to a bool and logical-and test it with the bool conversion of the return value of exportcommamd.c_str().

You probably intended

```
system(outputdirectorycommand.c_str() + " && " + exportcommand.c_str());
```

Comment: i guess that works too however i think that the first answer is the path of least resistance still deserves an upvote though